# MySQL basic table pivoting

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I'm trying to pivot a table result that looks like.....

```
     -----------------------------------------------
    | personsID    |   personsWeight |  dateWeighed |
     -----------------------------------------------
    |          1   |      160        |   04/15/2011 |
     -----------------------------------------------
    |          1   |      161        |   04/18/2011 |
     -----------------------------------------------
    |          1   |      162        |   06/30/2011 |
     -----------------------------------------------
    |          1   |      163        |   07/11/2011 |
     -----------------------------------------------
    |          1   |      164        |   04/01/2012 |
     -----------------------------------------------
```

I want it to look like

```
     --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |  personsID   | 04/15/2011  | 04/18/2011 | 06/30/2011 | 07/11/2011 | 04/01/2012 |
     --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |        1     |     160     |   161      |     162    |     163    |    164     |
     --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. I've seen lots of examples where the column's are manually written (eg jan, feb,......, dec). I'm having a really hard time finding out how to generate the column names based on the values given in the original table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL does not have a PIVOT function so you will have to use an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression to transform the rows of data into columns.

If you have a set number or known number of values, then you can hard-code the query:

```
select personsId,
  sum(case when dateWeighed='2011-04-15' then personsWeight else 0 end) `04/15/2011`,
  sum(case when dateWeighed='2011-04-18' then personsWeight else 0 end) `04/18/2011`,
  sum(case when dateWeighed='2011-06-30' then personsWeight else 0 end) `06/30/2011`
from yt
group by personsId;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b75d4/5).

But if you have an unknown number of `dates` that you want to turn into columns, then you will want to use a prepared statement to generate dynamic SQL:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'sum(CASE WHEN dateWeighed = ''',
      dateWeighed,
      ''' THEN personsWeight else 0 END) AS `',
      date_format(dateWeighed, '%m/%d/%Y'), '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM yt;

SET @sql 
  = CONCAT('SELECT personsId, ', @sql, ' 
            from yt
            group by personsId');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b75d4/6). Both will give the result:

```
| PERSONSID | 04/15/2011 | 04/18/2011 | 06/30/2011 | 07/11/2011 | 04/01/2012 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|         1 |        160 |        161 |        162 |        163 |        164 |
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was hoping the answer wouldn't be quite so difficult but thank you very much for taking the time to address it.